# Why does my Python script not work at all?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, fibonacci

I'm writing this code for something called 'Project Euler' which is basically a maths/computer science thing online, the link of which can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/about):

So anyway, when I run my code which is in Python 3.5, it doesn't do anything in the shell except the cursor bit blinks.
Here is the code in question:

```
`mylist=[]
a=1
b=2
c=a+b
def fib():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=a+b
    a=b
    b=c
    c=a+b
if a%2==0:
    mylist.append(a) and print(a)
elif b%2==0:
    mylist.append(b) and print(b)
elif c%2==0:
    mylist.append(c) and print(c)
else:
    print(end='')
while a and b and c<4000000:
    fib()
print(sum(mylist))'
```

The question I'm trying to answer is

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

The code is meant to add even Fibonacci numbers up to 4 million to a list and then print the sum of them which would perfectly answer the question but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It doesn't output anything because you told it to do so. You only call the function `fib()` (maybe) four million times and that function does nothing but setting some unused variables.

Comment: BTW: You seem to have a misconception about the `and` keyword which is a logical conjunction and not for "concatenating" commands.

Comment: Honestly, you're misusing "if", "and" keywords here, and your logic is sort of obscure, you might want to rewrite it after researching how to write a Fibonacci first.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Monkey Supersonic. Would it be better to then indent the `list.append` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created an infinite loop here:

```
while a and b and c < 4000000:
```

This translates to "while a is truthy and b is truthy and c is less than 4000000", and this will always be `True` so your while loop will never terminate. What I mean by "truthy" is: does `bool(value)` return `True`? If so, then `value` is "truthy". So `1`, `'hello'`, `[]`, etc., are truthy, and `0`, `False`, `[]`, etc., are not (they are "falsey"). I will not comment on all of your logic because you will benefit more from solving the problem on your own. However, here are a few tips that should get you unstuck:

1. if you want to check that `a`, `b`, and `c` are *all* less than `4000000`, than you can do this:

   ```
   while a < 4000000 and b < 4000000 and c < 4000000:
   ```

   or more succinctly:

   ```
   while all(i < 4000000 for i in [a, b, c]):
   ```
2. In order to not create an infinite loop, you will need to make sure that either `a`, `b`, or `c` will be greater than 4000000 at some point in your program by incriminating their values. The math you do on `a`, `b`, and `c` *inside* your `fib()` function only manipulates three variables called `a`, `b`, and `c` that are local to that function; it does not change the values of the `a`, `b`, and `c` *outside* of that function.

Comment: Thank you very much @elethan, I will definitely take both into account!